# google maps api for webview

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps-api-3

I’m developing an app that integrates Google map with Google places in a webview.  I have it all working well using the JavascriptInterface.  Actually it’s working really well.  However, I just want to know how to set the API key.

At the moment I’m using:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=true

I want to add the API key.  If I add the API key to the above JavaScript I get a message from Google blocking the connection saying that I have to register  the URL, which I can’t do as it is integrated in the app.

I have set the SHA key in the Google API Console.

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance.
.

Answer (score 0):

u should register your website to google map apis key page there is a button rightof key called Edit allowed referers...
and when u are using key 
put it to "addyourkeyhere" in link. and set your sensor false or true.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AddYourKeyhere&sensor=false"/>
```